# Uploaded file in PHP can't be used in Bash script

Tags: php, html, bash, file-upload

Hi I use this simple code to upload "txt" file (index.html + upload.php). It works fine, uploaded txt file is saved on server and I can see txt content. Problem is only when I want to use the file as input in script to filter only some words from text. The script I use is:  http://pastebin.com/U9yJL0t0 I know that script is good. I tested it with manually created txt file through terminal and it works good. Problem is only with uploaded file usig HTML and PHP.

> **index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> **upload.php**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "/var/www/tmp/test/$mid.txt";
$target_file = $target_dir;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "txt") {
    echo "Sorry, only txt  files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you try to change permissions jf uploaded file (chmod)?

Comment: @Andriy, yes I have tried to chmod on file and folders too, but the same problem appears again.

Comment: @Nikolaus you get any errors? Maybe turning on `error_reporting` http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and see what errors will appear?

Comment: @divaka I can see errors in: "error.log" file, there aren't any errors..Upload seems runs   Ok without error, also script. But no content in file :(

Comment: So you are getting this: `Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.` ?

Comment: What I suggest is to check for upload errors. More info about the errors you could find here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: @Nikolaus in your question you say *"I can see txt content"* and now you say that the file content is empty, what is changed in your code?

Comment: @Cliff Burton, I can see only content of the file which was uploaded, but I can't see content of the file which was created by script.(converted file)

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, when PHP creates the file, the owner and group of the file is most likely www-data. You could run the script using sudo, or change the owner or permissions of the file. I recommend changing ownership for security reasons.

Here's the command for changing ownership:

```
chown username.username filename.txt
```

Comment: yes group of uploaded  file is www-data, I tried run script sudo,  I also tried chmod of the file and  directory. I tried also to change owner of the file using: "chown www-data:root 1.txt", but the same problem appers: no content in text file

Comment: I also change group: "chgrp group 1.txt",  but the same problem appers: no content in text file after using in script

Comment: I can't see you set $mid to be anything though. Weird that you get an uploaded file at all if this is in fact your working script. If you have an uploaded txt-file with content and the right permissions, the issue has to be in your bash script. Only thing I can think of is you testing a text-file you've written in Linux which works, and uploading from windows which doesn't work. If this is the case it might be a problem with newlines handling. Windows uses Carriage Return and new line, which is \r\n. This is just a guess though.